# Authentication with hash instead of login-password?

Tags: passwords, webserver, website, authentication, authorization

I look at an idea of simple authentication for website\webserver.

The user clicks **Create profile**.

The website engine generates a hash from a random set of 20 words, for example

```
7a639b05f08394030e8bd81f411eb44025b0df1d1809d618993f10624a020ace
```

User enter a hash in the login field or log in using the link

```
site.com/login/7a639b05f08394030e8bd81f411eb44025b0df1d1809d618993f10624a020ace
```

Is it safe to use a hash  instead of a login-password pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may accomplish what you want, provided the string is sufficiently long, but you will have effectively created a site no human could reliably login to. That you are using hashing rather than a some kind of unique-value-generator that provides a sting of x-length has no impact on the situation. nor does the number of phrases included in the value hashed.

the whole point of a hash is to verify a users input, not to be the input itself. what you suggest is susceptible to brute-force and doesn;t accomplish anything except to combine the username and password. you might as well just have a DB of passwords, and match people based on the password entered, which could never match another users password, as its now the users primary identification in your accounts DB.

so imagine I register for a user account on a normal website, and put in a username and a password.  The site never stores my password, but calculates a hash on it, and stores the hash. when I try to login, I send my username and password. the remote server hashes the password I submitted, looks up my username and retrieves the existing hash from the accounts DB, and compares them. if they match, I am authenticated. Note that its important that I provided the passphrase, and that it calculates to the same hash. that's how the server knows I know the password. Also note that the server doesn't have my password. people with access to its database can't login as me, because a fit hash algorithm is non-reversible.

There are systems that accept long strings as authentication (a very large keyspace makes bruteforcing problematic) so if you have a small number of users, complex sequences can be sufficient. this concept is often used in "API Keys" used to authenticate to web resources, but these keys are just a literal value. they are the password itself. The means by which you derive them is unimportant, so long as an adversary cannot predict them.

so hashing really has nothing to do with the problem or solution here. if you want to use the same long value for user identification and authentication, that's up to you, but do keep in mind, under your scheme no two users could ever be allowed to have the same ... well lets call it "identity string" since thats basically what you are now using it for. you might as well just require long usernames, and anyone who knows (or guesses) an existing username is automatically allowed in.

Remember, a password only has the strength of its `character-set^length`. but a username and password have the strength of the `username's character-ser^length * the passwords character-Set^length`. by requiring that an attacker guesses both correctly, you are multiplying the difficulty by huge vales.

Comment: To be fair though, "hash" authorization is the industry standard in a lot of computer to computer interaction. Except we then call them keys. As long as the key is long enough, it may even be safer than password and username combinations.

Comment: If the original value is not involved in the communication, then that its a hash of something is unimportant. really the only thing that is important is that its a sting of arbitrary length.  by that reasoning, you could say me thinking up a password for a site is "hashing". Keys are called Keys (not hashes) for a reason. you could hash a value if you wanted to, or you could just enter a random string of 64 characters. theres no difference. as such the algorithm has no reliance on hash algorithms. it only needs a unique value generator.

Comment: @Frank Thomas  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pylsa Thanks a lot!